# Database design when having either foreign key or string

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

In my application I'm creating a case having a supervisor, but as the supervisor can be either an employee or an external supervisor, I'd like to be able to save either an employee id for the internal reference or a string for the name of the external supervisors name.

How should I implement this? Is having a table "case" and the sub-tables "case_internal_sv" and "case_external_sv" the way to go?

Comment: Are external supervisors and internal supervisors specialized subclasses of supervisors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot of information in your question on which to base an answer.

If there is common data and functionality across all types of supervisors then you will probably want one table to hold that common data.  That table would establish the primary key values for supervisors and the case table would have a foreign key into this table.  Information that is unique to either internal or external supervisors would go into separate tables and those tables would also have a foreign key back to the common supervisor level data.

This design is superior because you only have one place to go in order to find a list of all supervisors and because you can enforce the supervisor / case relationship directly in the database without a lot of code or additional constraints to ensure that "one and only one" of two columns is populated.

It's sufficiently superior, from a database point of view, that I'd consider using this design even if the data for internal and external supervisors is completely disjoint (which it's unlikely to be).

Answer (score 0):

If your database allows you to define multiple primary keys you could have field employee and field employee_type combine to form the unique primary key.  If not you could have an autogenerated primary key for the table and have a field for employee type and a field for employee_id.

What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

Having tables too normalized can do more harm than help. You should evaluate the benefits/drawbacks of having sub-tables based on your requirements.

A simple solution can be to have a `'sv_type'` column in `'case'` table. And have two columns

- `'internal_sv_id'`, a nullable foreign key to the employee table
- `'external_sv_name'`, a nullable string to save external name.

Then check for supervisor in one of these two columns based on the `'sv_type'`

This design might not fully conform to 3rd normal form, but it can save lot of costly joins and allow integrity with employee table.

As for me, I'd go for the simplest solution in case of doubt.

Comment: That's my thought's exactly. Was thinking about making the two fields as you describe and make them nullable. Then maybe maybe create a constrain to require either to be filled.

Comment: This design is not simple and makes it quite difficult to ensure integrity -- it cannot be done simply with primary and foreign keys, and additional code to constrain the values in the two columns would be required.  The JOINs involved are unlikely to be costly considering that there cannot be that many supervisors in the world, especially when considered with the additional costs of building the user interface and enforcing the integrity across potentially multiple clients.